# Add postbackurl as a attribute to button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have a button, which `OnClick` stores some text to tables in a database.

All this in `asp.net` using `c#` and .NET Framework 4.0.

However, i need that, when click, the button executes the `OnClick` method, thing is doing right now, but ALSO, navigates to another page, to continue registration.

The registration form is about 9 pages, i know if i pass `postbackurl="url"` it navigates to another page/form, but then it doesn't executes the `OnClick` method.

```
<div style="text-align:right; margin-top:20px"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Curriculum" postbackurl="Envia2.aspx" OnClick="Button1_Click" CssClass="my_btn" /></div>
```

So, how can i 'attach' this attribute to the `OnClick` method?

Or there is another walkaround to this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button click event cannot perform both at the same time at client side - submit to server and redirect to another page.

Ideally, you do not want to insert each registration step into database. instead, you want to store them in session state. Then insert them into database at the final page.

Here is the example. Make sure you check validation on each step -

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
}

// Page1.aspx
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Click="SubmitButton_Click"
    Text="Continue to Step 2" />   

// Page1.aspx.cs
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customer = new Customer
    {
        FirstName = FirstNameTexBox.Text,
        LastName = LastNameTexBox.Text
    };
    Session["Customer"] = customer;

    // Redirect to page 2
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}

// Page2.aspx
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Click="SubmitButton_Click" 
    Text="Continue to Step 3" />  

// Page2.aspx.cs
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customer = Session["Customer"] as Customer;
    customer.Address = AddressTextBox.Text;
    Session["Customer"] = customer;

    // Redirect to page 3
    Response.Redirect("Page3.aspx");
}

// Page9.aspx
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Click="SubmitButton_Click" 
    Text="Submit" /> 

// Page9.aspx.cs
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customer = Session["Customer"] as Customer;
    customer.Other = OtherTextBox.Text;

    // Save customer to database.
}
```

Comment: Gonna try your solution, seems like Response.Redirect doesn't works in these circumstances. I'll post you back later, thank you.

Comment: @KristianKoci I saw your question posted in answer area. You should never use **Response.Redirect** from data access class. It should be from either **System.Web.UI.Page (aspx)** Or **System.Web.UI.UserControl (ascx)**.

Comment: So i can add it to Button for example in .aspx?

Comment: You want to user **Response.Redirect** inside Button's Click event.

Comment: Exactly, should i add it like this? OnClick="Button1_Click.Response.Redirect("Envia2.aspx")" ?

Comment: Should i add this regardless of the method i already have to submit data to the database? The textboxes in your example are just parameters to identify user session right?

Comment: SO is not design like forum - answering back and forward. You are missing too many basic concepts in ASP.Net, and we are going cycle. I would like to suggest to read the following topic - Button Click event, Session state vs View State and Post Back. [Pro ASP.NET 4.5 in C#](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-4-5-Adam-Freeman/dp/143024254X/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1381782196&sr=8-5&keywords=asp.net)

Comment: Yes, i got confused with all the work i have, i'm sorry, and you're right, just adding 'Response.Redirect("page.aspx");' to ButtonClick event was enough, lol, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad that you figure out. My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you need to do two things when the user clicks the button:

1. Call "Button1_Click"
2. Post to "Envia2.apsx"

The problem is that 1. is itself consists of a form post to the current page (as you may know, ASP.Net server controls, in order to handle events on the server side, trigger a postback behind the scenes).  So I could see a few options:

1. Use `OnClick` and remove `postbackurl` -- inside the click handler, redirect to "Envia2.aspx"
2. Remove both `OnClick` and `postbackurl`.  Instead, make an Ajax call of some kind to invoke the "Button1_Click" code, and then when complete, call `form.post()` on the form that "Button1" belongs to.

Comment: Think first option suits better in this environment, do you know if 'Response.redirect' will do the trick, or which call should i add to the .cs?

Comment: @KristianKoci if you don't need any of the source page's form data, then a simple `Response.Redirect` should be fine.

Comment: Sorry if i ask, but what do you mean if i don't need any of the source page's form data? I click the button, and i have a function which stores all data into a db, then i'll add Response.Redirect, right? Or it wouldn't store anything on db? :(

Comment: @KristianKoci yes, that's fine -- everything before Response.Redirect is as normal.

Comment: Yeah, added to the Button_Click event and works perfectly now, thx!